# ASP.NET | 'ProjectStarter.Project' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a website in ASP.Net Webforms that works the same as www.kickstarter.com

After working and testing a lot I received this error:
*'ProjectStarter.Project' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments.*

I know what this error means, but the weird part is that I received this error for the first time when I didn't even changed something at this code, and I also tested the code and it worked fine before.

This is where I call the constructor and where it shows the error:

```
Project newproject = new Project(id,titel,imglink,kortebeschrijving);
```

And this is the constructor itself:

```
public Project(int id, string titel, string imglink, string kortebeschrijving)
    {
        this._id = id;
        this._titel = titel;
        this._imglink = imglink;
        this._kortebeschrijving = kortebeschrijving;
        this._projectlink = "Project.aspx?id=" + Convert.ToString(id);
    }
```

I have tried to restart Visual Studio but that didn't help. What could this be?

Comment: can you please show the class file for this..

Comment: Maybe clean and rebuild?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem....

I created a new page project.aspx and that automatically generates project.aspx.cs so it called the wrong constructor.